# Can I edit status bar height as spesific?

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS 11 due to status bar view goes down by 20 pixel,but works fine in iOS 10,[Status bar in iOS 11 by 20 more than regular in iOS 10

[image: status]

[In iOS 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp4yr.png)

for Generating custom Navigation bar
 In  class Base It is one of the function ,Inheriting this class to my view controller and just compiling.

In iOS 10 it shows as expected but not in iOS 11

```
     func setUpNavBar() {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true;

    navBar?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navBar?.lblTitle.text = self.title
    navBar?.ViewController = self




    navBar?.btnmenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navBar?.btnHome.addTarget(self, action: #selector(homeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(navBar!)
    let views = [ "navView": navBar]
    let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[navView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[navView(64)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)

    navBar?.internalview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addConstraints(horizontal)
    view.addConstraints(vertical)
}
```

Comment: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/ohw-to-ask

Comment: Are you use static view for navigation?

Comment: Hmm, It is custom view

Comment: In iOS 10 it works as expected but not in iOS 11

Comment: @Shivaareddy Why don't you show us the code. So we can try and help.

Comment: @sasquatch Added the Navigation bar code  in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your '64' value comes from the height of standard status bar (20) + the height of the navigation bar (44).

This works fine on iOS 10 because the view gets added at y = 0. On iOS 11, the view may not get added at zero due to the new 'safe area layouts', which may result in y = 20.

I believe in your case you would have to do something like the following:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[navView(44)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)
}
else {
  let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[navView(64)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, 
}
```